# Get the value from the JSON string

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and I am trying to convert the data to JSON so that I can send a message.

```
val df = Seq((123456, 40, "ABCD", "DEFG")).toDF("ID", "RunId", "Val1", "Val2")
val msgDf = df.select(struct("ID", "RunId", "Val1", "Val2").alias("message"))
msgDf.toJSON.show(false)
```

Schema for msgDf

```
message:struct
      ID:integer
      RunId:integer
      Val1:string
      Val2:string
```

Output I am getting is

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"message":{"ID":123456,"RunId":40,"Val1":"ABCD","Val2":"DEFG"}}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I just want to capture the below and send it as messgage

```
{"ID":123456,"RunId":40,"Val1":"ABCD","Val2":"DEFG"}
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: using version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_json` method as

```
val df = Seq((123456, 40, "ABCD", "DEFG"))
  .toDF("ID", "RunId", "Val1", "Val2")

val msgDf = df.select(to_json(struct("ID", "RunId", "Val1", "Val2")).as("message"))
```

Or simply

```
df.select(to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*)).alias("message"))

msgDf.show(false)
```

Or

```
Seq((123456, 40, "ABCD", "DEFG")).toDF("ID", "RunId", "Val1", "Val2")
  .toJSON.show(false)
```

Result:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|message                                             |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|{"ID":123456,"RunId":40,"Val1":"ABCD","Val2":"DEFG"}|
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `struct` - doing `toJSON` directly will do the job:

```
val df = Seq((123456, 40, "ABCD", "DEFG")).toDF("ID", "RunId", "Val1", "Val2")

df.toJSON.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------+
|value                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|{"ID":123456,"RunId":40,"Val1":"ABCD","Val2":"DEFG"}|
+----------------------------------------------------+
```